# How to combine JSR-303/JSR-349 bean validation with own org.springframework.validation.Validator validation?

Tags: java, spring, validation

I need to do validation manually (because I need to use `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` and because this resolver I cannot use `BindingResult` in method parameters) in POJO class and custom validation in `org.springframework.validation.Validator`. Please see my code.

**Controller class**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authorize", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public String authorize(@Valid AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest) {

        // JSR-303/JSR-349 bean validation
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<AuthorizationRequest>> violations = validator.validate(authorizationRequest);

        // Own org.springframework.validation.Validator
        BindingResult result = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(authorizationRequest, "request");
        AuthorizationRequestValidator validator2 = new AuthorizationRequestValidator();
        validator2.validate(authorizationRequest, result);
}
```

**POJO** class:

```
public class AuthorizationRequest {

    @NotEmpty
    @JsonProperty("response_type")
    private String responseType;

    @NotEmpty
    @JsonProperty("client_id")
    private String clientId;

    @NotEmpty
    @JsonProperty("redirect_uri")
    private String redirectUri;

//getter, setters omitted 

}
```

and `org.springframework.validation.Validator` **validator**

```
@Component
public class AuthorizationRequestValidator implements Validator {

    private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AuthorizationRequestValidator.class);

    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return AuthorizationRequest.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {
        AuthorizationRequest request = (AuthorizationRequest) obj;
        if ("foobar".equals(request.getClientId())) {
            e.rejectValue("clientId", "nomatch");
        }
    }

}
```

**Question**

I would like to do both validation in the same time and combine output of these two validations within Spring. Is there some way how to combine it or do I have to do it manually?

**Resolver** class (only for clarification):

```
public class AuthorizationRequestResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AuthorizationRequestResolver.class);

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterType().equals(AuthorizationRequest.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter,
                                  ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                                  NativeWebRequest webRequest,
                                  WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) webRequest.getNativeRequest();

        AuthorizationRequest authRequest = mapFromServletRequest(request);
        return authRequest;

    }

    private AuthorizationRequest mapFromServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = new AuthorizationRequest();
        authorizationRequest.setClientId(request.getParameter("client_id"));
        authorizationRequest.setRedirectUri(request.getParameter("request_uri"));
        authorizationRequest.setResponseType(request.getParameter("response_type"));
        authorizationRequest.setScope(request.getParameter("scope"));
        authorizationRequest.setState(request.getParameter("state"));
        return authorizationRequest;
    }

}
```